# Why is quicksort used in practice?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Quicksort has a worst-case performance of O(n<sup>2</sup>), but is still used widely in practice anyway.  Why is this?

Answer (score 25):

You shouldn't center only on worst case and only on time complexity. It's more about average than worst, and it's about time **and** space.

Quicksort:

- has average time complexity of Θ(*n* log *n*);
- can be implemented with space complexity of Θ(log *n*);

Also have in account that big O notation doesn't take in account any constants, but in practice it does make difference if the algorithm is few times faster. Θ(*n* log *n*) means, that algorithm executes in *K* *n* log(*n*), where *K* is constant. Quicksort is the comparison-sort algorithm with the lowest *K*.

Answer (score 7):

Average asymptotic order of QuickSort is `O(nlogn)` and it's usually more efficient than heapsort due to smaller constants (tighter loops). In fact, there is a theoretical linear time median selection algorithm that you can use to always find the best pivot, thus resulting a worst case `O(nlogn)`. However, the normal QuickSort is usually faster than this theoretical one.

To make it more sensible, consider the probability that QuickSort will finish in `O(n`<sup>`2`</sup>`)`. It's just `1/n!` which means it'll almost never encounter that bad case.

Comment: The fact that QS partitions, means that eventually the partition size will allow it to fit entirely into cache.  This makes for fast processing, particularly when compared with stuff like the bubble sort, that makes repeated passes over full data set.   I claim that partitioning type sorts, will tend to run better with smaller working sets, then other kinds.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, quicksort performs more comparisons on average than mergesort - 1.44 n lg n (expected) for quicksort versus n lg n for mergesort.  If all that mattered were comparisons, mergesort would be strongly preferable to quicksort.

The reason that quicksort is fast is that it has many other desirable properties that work extremely well on modern hardware.  For example, quicksort requires no dynamic allocations.  It can work in-place on the original array, using only O(log n) stack space (worst-case if implemented correctly) to store the stack frames necessary for recursion.  Although mergesort can be made to do this, doing so usually comes at a huge performance penalty during the merge step.  Other sorting algorithms like heapsort also have this property.

Additionally, quicksort has excellent locality of reference.  The partitioning step, if done using Hoare's in-place partitioning algorithm, is essentially two linear scans performed inward from both ends of the array.  This means that quicksort will have a very small number of cache misses, which on modern architectures is critical for performance.  Heapsort, on the other hand, doesn't have very good locality (it jumps around all over an array), though most mergesort implementations have reasonably locality.

Quicksort is also very parallelizable.  Once the initial partitioning step has occurred to split the array into smaller and greater regions, those two parts can be sorted independently of one another.  Many sorting algorithms can be parallelized, including mergesort, but the performance of parallel quicksort tends to be better than other parallel algorithms for the above reason.  Heapsort, on the other hand, does not.

The only issue with quicksort is the possibility that it degrades to O(n<sup>2</sup>), which on large data sets can be very serious.  One way to avoid this is to have the algorithm introspect on itself and switch to one of the slower but more dependable algorithms in the case where it degenerates.  This algorithm, called [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), is a great hybrid sorting algorithm that gets many of the benefits of quicksort without the pathological case.

In summary:

- Quicksort is in-place except for the stack frames used in the recursion, which take O(log n) space.
- Quicksort has good locality of reference.
- Quicksort is easily parallelized.

This accounts for why quicksort tends to outperform sorting algorithms that on paper might be better.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because on average it's the fastest comparison sort (in terms of elapsed time).

Answer (score 1):

Because, in the general case, it's one of the fastest sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being the fastest though, some of it's bad case scenarios can be avoided by shuffling the array before sorting it. As for it's weakness with small data sets, obviously isn't as big a problem since the datasets are small and the sort time is probably small regardless.

As an example, I wrote a python function for QuickSort and bubble sorts. The bubble sort takes  ~20 seconds to sort 10,000 records, 11 seconds for 7500, and 5 for 5000.  The quicksort does all these sorts in around 0.15 seconds!

Comment: Any reasonable sort is going to perform much better than bubblesort. Try comparing it to mergesort, heapsort, or blocksort. Also, shuffling an almost sorted list before feeding it into quicksort feels like a waste of a good opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth pointing out that C does have the library function `qsort()`, but there's no requirement that it be implemented using an actual QuickSort, that is up to the compiler vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Bcs this is one of Algorithm with work well on large data set with O(NlogN) complexity. This is also in place algorithm which take constant space. By selecting pivot element wisely we can avoid worse case of Quick sort and will perform in O(NlogN) always even on sorted array.